# Failed to connect RDS server through RDP

Tags: windows, rds

I have an issue with a RDS server (Windows 2012R2)
I had to migrate this server to a new domain, but since it's impossible to login through RDP.

When I try to connect this server from a Windows client I have the error:
 "This computer can't connect to the remote computer. Try connection again. If the problem continues, contact the owner of the remote computer or your network administrator."

No other events in the server log or client log.

So I decided to uninstall the RDS role on this server. After that, I was able to connect through RDP. I tried to reinstall the role, the problem occur again.

After investigations, I found that when I set the MinEncryption Level to 1 (https://www.mvps.net/docs/how-to-secure-remote-desktop-rdp/) the connection works.

I think the problem is when the TLS session is initiated.

I decided to renew all the certificates for the server, broker and licence manager (which is the same machine).
Register the licence manager server again (no error in the licence diagnostic)
Delete registry key in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server\RCM

Still no luck.

Comment: Relevant logs files that you should read: 
Event Viewer -> Applications and services logs -> Microsoft -> Windows -> `RemoteApp and Desktop connections` and everything starting by `RemoteDesktopServices` + everything starting by `TerminalServices`

Answer (score 2):

I finally found the solution.
There was an error in the log "TerminalServices-SessionsBroker-Client",  Error ID 1296 (Remote Desktop Connection Broker Client failed while getting redirection packet from Connection Broker.)

I had to specify the FQDN of the broker in the local policy

Local Computer Policy/Computer Configuration/Administrative Templates/Windows Components/Remote Desktop Services/Remote Desktop Session Host/RD Connection Broker/

"Configure RD Connection Broker server name"

Restart the server, and now it works

Comment: Thank you, It resolved my problem.